# Writing Shapes with GeoTools: Data fields with UTF-8 content are invalid

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, utf-8

i'm creating Shapes using GeoTools SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeatureBuilder and featureBuilder.add(...). (i can add snips if requested)

Data Source is postgresql.

Displaying the shapes with QGIS shows "???" in the locname field (there should be "東京都" for Tokyo) same problems for wikimedia.

[image]

Last year, i did the conversion postgresql -> shape using pgsql2shp, which was running fine. No, i can't switch back to that!

[image]

Is there any way to specify which encoding to use in geoTools? Or whatelse am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The shapefile standard is old and the original/official version only allowed for ISO-8851 characters. GeoTools by default generates compliant shapefiles in ISO-8851.

If you want you can instruct it to generate DBFs in UTF-8, see the documentation here:
http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html

Comment: ok, osm2pgsql does not "respect" the standard - and that was fine for me ;)

Tnx for pointing to the solution, i'll install it at once.

Comment: running fine :)

Comment: sorry: pgsql2shp, not osm2pgsql